# Get URL from file_get_contents()

Tags: php, api

I am writing API for one service, and now I need to restrict some calls for some URL. Let's say that you are user and you choose that only stackoverflow.com can see your information, or that stackoverflow.com, facebook.com and google.com cannot see your information.

I have the system on the backend (white vs. black lists) but now I need to find a way to get the URL from the call.

Yes some people will be using curl and it will be easy, but a lot of people will simply use file_get_contents(), as well as this API has an image output so some people will use

```
<img src="http://domain.com/api/something.jpg" />
```

Any thoughts how to get the url, without having developers to actually encode the url into calling url?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the IP address (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`) of the requesting client. You can whitelist IP addresses of the servers allowed to connect to your API. For the image output, you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and ensure that it is from a domain you have whitelisted.

However, I am not recommending this implementation. You should make use of API keys. These are like passwords given to clients using your API. Only those with API keys can access your API. At the same time, when their servers change IP addresses, they will still be able to access your API.

Comment: Yes I will be using API keys, but I don't expect every single webmaster of some small website to go to my service, register and apply for API key. I need to write this the way that it is extremely easy to implement, but unfortunately great privacy issues are involved.

Comment: I will be writing library eventually for easy implementation which will be using curl, but again, not everyone will go and download the library and implement it to their website. Not everyone can as well. that's why I'm looking for something simple as file_get_contents('http://domain/something.json');

Comment: Okay, you can do the suggestion I made in the first paragraph.

Comment: Problem with the first paragraph is that REMOTE_ADDR can be overcome easy and, as you mentioned, IP addresses can change. HTTP_REFERER is also problematic, since it doesn't have to be set always, and it seems like not working in IE. The purpose of image output is to give people chance to use the api, even if they are not webmasters of the page they want to display the information at. For example in the forums, they could include the image output in their signature. So it is not very important as not many people will use it, so I guess Referer in this case could be valid way to go

Comment: You mean it can be tampered? IP Addresses may not be tampered. If actual servers will be connecting to the API, you just need to whitelist the IP addresses of those servers. You can probably setup a registration page wherein they put their server's IP. I agree with you regarding the HTTP_REFERER. Maybe you can make the image output public? So you don't need to check the HTTP_REFERER, just let anyone access it. Besides, its design is for public use based on your description. For the API keys, just give it to people and they use: file_get_contents('domain/file.php?api_key=sgfdgsdfg52g...');

Comment: I cannot just let the image output be public. The API output will contain sensitive personal information and from my research, many people can be in control where these information can be displayed. What I meant was that servers could hide behind proxy or any other IP changing bots. I am not sure what you mean by just give the api keys to people. It is probably more complex than you would guess. Each user can have unlimited websites connected (actually website is nothing in this project,but people tend to restrict their privacy to websites)

Comment: Then for each website they create groups of informations they want to get from users and each of those groups have its own API key. User cannot deny to display information under this API key, but cna deny information form any other group. I guess I would have to show all algorythms, but thats really for long, I was just looking if there would be any simple way.

Comment: These groups must use their API key to access the API. That would ensure that the API is only accessible to people you authorize. That's what I meant by "give keys to people."

Comment: Well yes they will be passing the API key, but that will authorize them to just get the data more efficient or to get set of private data. But other than that API is open to public and anyone can access it without an API key